# Why the field section does not get embedded

Tags: go

I have the following struct

```
package router

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "townspeech/components/i18n"
    "townspeech/components/policy"
    "townspeech/components/session"
    "townspeech/controllers/base"
    "townspeech/types"
)

type sidHandler struct {
    req     *http.Request
    res     http.ResponseWriter
    handler sidFuncHandler
    section string
    err     *types.ErrorJSON
    sess    *session.Sid
}
```

And I want to embed in another struct like:

```
package router

import (
    "net/http"
    "townspeech/types"
    "townspeech/components/session"
    "townspeech/controllers/base"
)

type authHandler struct {
    sidHandler
    handler authFuncHandler
    auth    *session.Auth
}
```

And the function, that use the authHandler struct:

```
func registerAuthHandler(handler authFuncHandler, section string) http.Handler {
    return &authHandler{handler: handler, section: section}
}
```

The compiler complain:

```
# app/router
../../../router/funcs.go:9: unknown authHandler field 'section' in struct literal
FAIL    app/test/account/validation [build failed]
```

As you can see, the two structs are in the same package, field section should not appear as private.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding doesn't work with literals like that.

```
func registerAuthHandler(handler authFuncHandler, section string) http.Handler {
    return &authHandler{
        handler: handler,
        sidHandler: sidHandler{section: section},
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to promoted fields in a struct literal. You have to create the embedded type, and refer to it by the type's name.

```
&authHandler{
    sidHandler: sidHandler{section: "bar"},
    handler:    "foo",
}
```